# What does /sys/class/net/eth1/carrier show? And how to make it 1?

Tags: network-interface, kernel-modules, hardware, ethernet, internet

I think it's the hardware connection, because when I unplug the ethernet cable for eth0, carrier goes from 1 to 0.

However, on my eth1 connection (using qca7000 driver for a redbeet carrier module) my carrier is always 0, even though dmesg shows that a connection was established.

Why is this?

Here are the results from `ethtool eth1`:

[image]

And `lshw -c network -sanitize`

[image]

`dmesg`

[image]

Comment: Your issue might be due to Secure boot and improper kernel signature (that you can't do yourself anyway without much more efforts because you don't have the key). Try disabling UEFI Secure boot and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I believe it just means the device is running at half duplex. Are you using raaspberry pi and and a device connected to the GPIO pins as an ethernet device?  In any case, since it's hafl duplex, only 1 side of the connection can transfer data at time. The clock speed is correct. And the module is tainted because it's propriety software.

Comment: The RED beet is not really an Ethernet NIC, but a HomePlug GreenPHY powerline communications adapter. The code is in Linux kernel: the message `SPI thread created` comes from [line 573 of qca_spi.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/qualcomm/qca_spi.c?h=v5.11.10#n573) and it seems to me it only implies the driver has taken control of the card... but it doesn't mean that the link has come up yet.

Comment: @A.B I'm using a NanoPi Core running Armbian software. It seems EUFI is not supported on this setup (https://forum.armbian.com/topic/5070-u-boot-uefi/)

Comment: @CinaedSimson Yes you are right but the device is a NanoPi Core. I ran the same thing on a Raspberry Pi, and even though that was also half duplex, carrier was equal to 1. So the issue is probably something else it seems

Comment: oh ok. I was confused by the module verification error.